# USB 2.0 touchscreen monitor 10'' to 15''

Tags: monitors, touchscreen

Basically searching for [DoubleSight DS-10UT](https://www.doublesight.com/shop/product.asp?idx=139) but bigger (13 inches seems ideal).

Requirements are following:

- USB **only**, ideally signal and power in single cable. No
  HDMI/DVI/DSUB + USB, USB+Power is acceptable.
- Touchscreen without additional cables
- USB 2.0 compatible. USB 3 device backward compatible with 2, but at lower fps/resolution is still ok.
- VESA ([Adapter](https://www.doublesight.com/shop/product.asp?idx=73) is acceptable)
- Windows compatible.

Aside of DoubleSight, which is almost perfect aside of small size, I can't find device fitting all points. There is bunch of cool new devices from [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/Portable-Products/) and similar, but touchscreen is rare and USB 3/USB C very common.

I am aware of USB graphic adapters and horrible ways of abusing tablets, but simplicity is preffered.

Comment: I have a UHD USB 3.0 monitor, and when I plug it into a USB 2.0 port, it still works, but the resolution choices are 800x600 and 1024x768.  I suspect that USB 2.0 monitors only support 1024x768 resolution max, due to the USB 2.0 speed limitations.

Comment: @Alex  I would not be surprised if pure USB devices simply had USB hub and VGA adapter inside. If your device fits my needs, an answer with more device info would be very nice :)